# Edit Registrations/Edit in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Started to learn and develop rails - while it is pretty straight forward I got stuck changing the implementation of the `/users/edit` view and endpoint in the default configuration of devise.

My approach is pretty simple, all routes and logic for authentication, password resetting etc. get handled by devise and it's routes. My problem is that I want users to change their passwords and email via my custom `/settings` route and view. For me `/users/edit` just doesn't make sense and I want to remove it from the accessible routes and ideally use its logic for my custom route.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    # Defines the root path route ("/")
    root "home#index"

    # SETTINGS
    get "settings/profile" => "settings#profile"
    get "settings/account" => "settings#account"
    get "settings/billing" => "settings#billing"
    get "settings/notifications" => "settings#notifications"

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
           :confirmable, :lockable,
           :trackable, :omniauthable

    def remember_me
        true
    end
end
```

**settings_controller.rb**

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    
    def profile
    end

    def account
    end

    def billing
    end

    def notifications
    end
end
```

Comment: You can make some routing directing to your own views. Though you still need your forms to direct to Devise controllers. Regarding the views just mimick Devise ones here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/tree/main/app/views/devise that include default path to Devise controllers. Also you probably may need more than one "profile" method as you want to Show the profile and Edit it.

Comment: By doing so I always get error because rails can’t find „ressource“ which is used in forms. Maybe you can point out a better or more complete example?

Comment: You can tweak your forms. For example this is Devise first line of default login form : `form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|` that you can turn into `form_with(model: User, url: user_session_path) do |f|` so that you get rid of resource.

Comment: Basically with Devise you can also generate views and controllers so that they appear in your app. You can tweak these `new` and `edit` views to blend into your app. And then you can keep the default forms with `resource`. Otherwise if you want to use your own forms anywhere in your app, you have to get rid of `resource` and add model and path for the very Devise model you are referring to.